# What is cause of Terraform putting CloudWatch Logs Destination Policy

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

This Terraform error:

> Error: putting CloudWatch Logs Destination Policy (exp-mgt-connect-kinesis-destination): operation error CloudWatch Logs: PutDestinationPolicy, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 9ed8bf2f-715a-49eb-aee3-b928f7a3955a, InvalidParameterException: Only one principal block is supported.
> │
> │   with aws_cloudwatch_log_destination_policy.destination_policy,
> │   on main.tf line 128, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_destination_policy" "destination_policy":
> │  128: resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_destination_policy" "destination_policy"

is the result of applying this Terraform code:

```
resource "aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream" "kinesis_firehose_stream" {
  name        = "exp-mgt-${var.s3_bucket_prefix}-delivery-stream"
  destination = "extended_s3"

  extended_s3_configuration {
    role_arn       = aws_iam_role.firehose_role.arn
    bucket_arn     = "arn:aws:s3:::${var.s3_bucket_name}"
    buffering_size = 64
    prefix         = var.s3_bucket_prefix
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "cwl_to_firehose_role" {
  name = "CWLtoKinesisFirehoseRole"

  # Trusted entities
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
           "Service": "logs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
        },
        "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "inline_cloudwatch_policy" {
  name     = "Permissions-Policy-For-CWL"
  role     = aws_iam_role.cwl_to_firehose_role.id

  policy = jsonencode({
    Version: "2012-10-17",
    Statement: [
        {
          Sid: "FirehoseAccess1",
          Effect: "Allow",
          Action: "firehose:ListDeliveryStreams",
          Resource: "*"
        },
        {
          Sid: "Passrole",
          Effect: "Allow",
          Action: "iam:PassRole",
          Resource: aws_iam_role.cwl_to_firehose_role.arn
        },
        {
          Sid: "FirehoseAccess2",
          Effect: "Allow",
          Action: [
                "firehose:DescribeDeliveryStream",
                "firehose:PutRecord",
                "firehose:PutRecordBatch"
            ],
          Resource: aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.kinesis_firehose_stream.arn
        }
    ]
  })
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_destination" "exp_mgt_destination" {
  name       = "exp-mgt-${var.s3_bucket_prefix}-kinesis-destination"
  role_arn   = aws_iam_role.cwl_to_firehose_role.arn
  target_arn = aws_kinesis_firehose_delivery_stream.kinesis_firehose_stream.arn
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "destination_policy" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = [
      "logs:PutSubscriptionFilter",
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_cloudwatch_log_destination.exp_mgt_destination.arn,
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_destination_policy" "destination_policy" {
  destination_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_destination.exp_mgt_destination.name
  access_policy    = data.aws_iam_policy_document.destination_policy.json
}
```

What is causing this `InvalidParameterException: Only one principal block is supported.` error?

Answer (score 1):

This error happens because the policy document of `data.aws_iam_policy_document.destination_policy` is missing `principal`, while `aws_cloudwatch_log_destination_policy` resource type requires the principal to be defined.

Take a look at the example from the official docs:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudwatch_log_destination_policy

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "test_destination_policy" {
  statement {
    effect = "Allow"

    principals {
      type = "AWS"

      identifiers = [
        "123456789012",
      ]
    }

    actions = [
      "logs:PutSubscriptionFilter",
    ]

    resources = [
      aws_cloudwatch_log_destination.test_destination.arn,
    ]
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_destination_policy" "test_destination_policy" {
  destination_name = aws_cloudwatch_log_destination.test_destination.name
  access_policy    = data.aws_iam_policy_document.test_destination_policy.json
}
```

In the example, policy contains single principal tag, which points to the ID of AWS account. It means access to the Cloudwatch log destination will be managed by the account's IAM roles/policies.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It has fixed my problem.